# Render coloring question

Tags: rendering

So I made a platform like you would see in a tron game. There's an outline of the object that I colored orange and the rest is black. My problem is that when I render the object with f12, all I see is the black color. Is there a way to make the render show the orange outline too?

Comment: Please place an image your question.  Show your outliner and objects.  Blender Render or Cycles Render?

Comment: Make sure you have multiple lights in the scene.

Comment: @John please edit your post and add more information to your question. We have no clue how your materials are set up, what kind of render engine you are using, how your lights are set, etc. Consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the link to your post so that someone can help you out.